# How to display information about the current user in Mojo :: Log

Tags: perl, mojolicious

The logs display information by default. Using the _default function in Mojo::Log.

```
sub _default {
  my ($time, $level) = (shift, shift);
  my ($s, $m, $h, $day, $month, $year) = localtime $time;
  $time = sprintf '%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%08.5f', $year + 1900, $month + 1, $day, $h, $m,
    "$s." . ((split /\./, $time)[1] // 0);
  return "[$time] [$$] [$level] " . join "\n", @_, '';
}
```

It is necessary to add information about the current user (for example, his ID). An App :: Controller object is required to retrieve user information.
Is it possible to override the resulting $app->log using the before_dispatch function?

```
$app->hook(before_dispatch => sub($c){...});
```

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can change the format of the logger by setting [the `format` property](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Log#format). That part is fairly trivial.

```perl
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;

helper user => sub ($c) {
    return "bob";
};

get '/' => sub ($c) {
    app->log->warn('hello');
    $c->render(text => "Hello");
};

app->log->format( sub { app->user . ": " . join "\n", @_, '' } );
app->start;
```

This will work. The trick here is to use something that isn't part of the arguments the format code reference gets passed in, and to close over that. It works well with `app`.

You are saying your user information comes from a different controller. That is a bit strange. Shouldn't the context contain the information about the current user?

Comment: I haven't found a way to get `$c` into the format sub. There's probably a way to do it though. If you look at modules on CPAN in the Mojo::Log:: namespace, none of them do it.

Comment: At your example `app` has no acces to current request, so it can not access session value. I do not understand how this will work. `app` just builds empty controller object without context.

Comment: @len8200 I know. I'm not sure about it either. I don't use Mojo regularly, so I don't really know where to dig or what's typical. My point was, you can overwrite the format. You could probably write a helper or something that DSL-y that has access to the context and use that in place of `app->log->warn`, and make it set the format every time. Or make a custom logger that is aware of the current context or something. There are ways, but most of them seem rather convoluted.

Comment: I also have that suggestion, but looking for real solution.

Comment: @len it might help to know a bit more about your architecture. Can you make an [mcve] similar to in my answer with two controllers?